# Fixed table header which won't float under fixed menu at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a little something (maybe jQuery plugin) that will make my table header fixed while scrolling the page AND **won't float it under the fixed positioned menu**, but rather stop it at the menu's bottom.

Also I don't want to specify the exact dimensions of the table (or its container) forcing the table to display scrollbars.

These my requests is not able to fulfil any plugin I tried.

---

**Edit:**

Here is a little example of what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/GLCdK/

Comment: have you tried jquery plugin..fixedheader..here is the link..http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. It would help a lot if you could provide a picture or example of what you want versus what the problem is, so that others can more easily help you.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/oma/table-fixed-header) is probably what you are looking for, but you may find you need to use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), but try it and see how you get on.

Comment: @sasi Yes I tried it, it is not doing what I want.